# How to explain the difference between the FFT result and the analytical Fourier transform?

Tags: python, programming, fast-fourier-transform

I am learning FFT by scipy's 'fft'. And now I have the rectangle function as shown below.

[image]

Its analytical Fourier transform is

[image]

and its squared absolute value is

[image]

For performing FFT, I sampled the `f(x)` in the range `0 <= x <= 10`. And the number of samples `N` is 2**18, such that sample interval `delt` is `10.0/(2**18-1)`. The FFT snippet is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft

# Define the analytical form of the Fourier transform
def fk(k):
    value = 2*(1-np.cos(k))/(k**2 + 0.0001)   # '0.0001' is used to aovid the singularity
    return value


N = 2**18
delt = 10.0/(N-1)                              # sample interval
y_time = np.loadtxt("data_input_b_262144.dat") # read-in the sample points
y_freq = fft(y_time)                           # perform fft
y_freq_square =(delt**2)* np.abs(y_freq)**2   # The squared absolute value of magnitude of frequencce component

# Positive frequency
k = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*delt), int(N/2))

# Plot the spectrum
plt.plot(k, y_freq_square[0:int(N/2)],
         k,fk(k))
plt.gca().set_xlim(0.1, np.amax(k))
plt.gca().set_ylim(0.001, 1.2)
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('$\hat f(k)$')
plt.legend(['fft result', 'analytical fourier transform'])
plt.savefig('rectangle_fft.png')
```

The figure is

[image]

So **my question** is that why does there exist differences between these two results? In principle, they are supposed to be the same curve in the figure.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: 'analytical' is plotting only half of the frequencies, not the fft.

Comment: @reuns So how should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: The main thing I see is that (as pointed by reuns) the analytical signal is not the same as the signal itself (it is a Hilbert transform, see [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/ACHA.w14/analytic_signal.pdf)). Besides,  what is your definition of the Fourier Transform ? With a $2 \pi $ factor or without it ?

Comment: Your statement "In principle, they are supposed to be the same curve" not correct. What is your source for this?

Comment: @JeanMarie without $2\pi$

Comment: @Somos For the same signal, why are there differences between its analytic Fourier Transform and the Fourier Transform computed by FFT?

Comment: How does the FFT depend on the number of samples?

Comment: Your question is predicated on ""In principle, they are supposed to be the same curve". What is the source of this incorrect statement? Why do you think it is true? Do you have any evidence in its favor?

Comment: I think the authors question is whether there is a way to approximate an analytical continuous variable by a FFT, right?